# Changing backgroundcolor of tooltip for a specific data point in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts line chart and have tooltips enabled, however, I would like to change the background color of tooltip for just a single data point on the chart.
Is it possible to do so?
What I have so far
`tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y;
            },
            backgroundColor: '#68BD49',
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: '1'
        },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, by using HTML option and define custom parameters. Obviously you can use CSS styles / classes disable padding/margins, but in the simplest way you can achive this in this way:

```
 tooltip: {
        useHTML:true,
        formatter: function() {
            console.log(this);
            if(this.point.customBck)
                return '<div style="background-color:red;">The value for <b>'+ this.x + '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b></div>';
            else
                return '<div>The value for <b>'+ this.x + '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b></div>';
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XnLpH/1/

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically set the entire tooltips background color? This only sets the background of the tooltip text..

Comment: In which condition it should be applied? Each point should have own backogrund or each series ?